# How to construct relations on the following domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, logic

Construct the following relations on the domain {1,2,3}.

- A relation that is transitive and symmetric, but not reflexive or antisymmetric.

How would I construct the above relation?

I have attempted similar problems with the two being below.

- A relation that is both symmetric and antisymmetric.

  {(1,2),(2,1),(3,2),(2,3)}
- A relation that is both transitive and not symmetric.

  {(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)}

Comment: Note that your example about a relation that is both symmetric and anti-symmetric is wrong. Why?

Comment: Would this be correct for the relation with symmetric and anti-symmetric? ````{(1,2),(2,1),(2,3)}````

Comment: To be antisymmetric, it must be that if $(1,2)$ is in the relation, then you *cannot have* $(2,1)$ in the relation.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a hint.

**Assume** that $(1,2)$ was part of this relation you want. Since the relation is symmetric, ...

> we must have $(2,1)$ in our relation.

Furthermore, since the relation is transitive, that means ...

> $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$, along with transitivity, imply that $(1,1)$ is also in our relation.

Now, what can be said about reflexivity?